# Apache rewrites for url with query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a list of urls to redirect.
A lot of them include query parameters.

So, for example, I need to redirect

```
index.php?id=627&type=98
```

to

```
/about-us/contact/
```

I thought that the following would work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^id=627&type=98$" [NC]
RewriteRule "^index\.php" "/about-us/contact/?" [NC,R,L]
```

But it is not working.
What is wrong with the Rewrite Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use quoted strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=627&type=98$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /about-us/contact/? [NC,R,L]
```

---

To put in site config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=627&type=98$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /about-us/contact/? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. I had it without quotes before, but then I had a / at the beginning of the RewriteSource. Such a stupid mistake...

Also it seems the rules don't work in the site config in apache, only in the .htaccess

Comment: If you want to put them in site config (recommended), I've added the subsection for that.